# How to add material to mesh generated by geometry nodes

Tags: materials, geometry-nodes

What I did is the following: I created a new material and set the attribute "material index" on every face to 1 (0 doesn't seem to work). However this does not seem to have an effect on the shading of the object.
I am using blender 2.93.0 - the latest stable blender version.

If you want to download the blend file you can do so [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QsPy4qdZP4KNPfVEuh1RJU6Z20DNYPSi/view?usp=sharing).

Here you can see the relevant data:
[image]

Comment: Why can’t you use the material assign node?

Comment: @Chris because I didn't know such a node existed. I am using blender 2.93 and not blender 3.0 . After looking into it, it seems like it is a 3.0 feature. Thank you very much.

Comment: I think it's a limitation of V2.93 GN unfortunately. The instanced mesh loses all links to the instancer object data, including materials. What's weird is if you go into edit mode, the mesh turns green. Might be a bug ?

Comment: @Gorgious In edit mode it gets green because geometry nodes are not taken into account.

Comment: @vklidu I beg to differ :) There is an inconsistency here. In V.2.93 the mesh turns green, in V3.00 it stays grey, and in both cases the GN modifier is executed : https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqmtx.png and https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mdb1c.png

Comment: I have the same problem, or similar. Not sure. But I assigned the materials to the geometry node icospheres using a Attribute Fill and assigning the material_index. I can only see the materials in edit mode. https://www.area.fullframestudios.ch/AREA/BlenderScreenshots/GeometryNodes_Icospheres_ObjectMode.png and https://www.area.fullframestudios.ch/AREA/BlenderScreenshots/GeometryNodes_Icospheres_EditMode.png Do we file a bug? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

Try linking your materials to *Object* rather than *Object Data* like illustrated below

[image]