# Assign materials to geometry node primitives

Tags: materials, geometry-nodes

I have two icospheres. One inside the other to represent a human cell.

I put 2 materials on the geometry in the "real world", meaning outside of the node network. I then assigned the materials using an Attribute Fill setting the material_index inside the node network.

For some reason the spheres still carry the default material in object mode and I only see the materials assigned inside the node network when I switch to edit mode.

Is there a way to do this without going to Blender v3 which has material nodes for the geometry nodes?

[image: Object Mode]

[image: Edit Mode]

Comment: Similar to https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/227175/how-to-add-material-to-mesh-generated-by-geometry-nodes It seems in V 293 it's not possible to assign a material to instanced (object-less) geometry. Might be a bug though since the material is correctly applied when switching to edit-mode as you noticed

Comment: So how can I trak if this is s bug and is dealt with? Do I have to report it? I would like to avoid going v3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try linking your materials to *Object* rather than *Object Data* like illustrated below

[image]